# How to export multiple data frames to CSV?

Tags: r, csv, export

**Situation**: I have several data frames that I like to export as CSV files into the working directory for further processing.

**Goal**: Export a collection of data frames from the workspace as csv files to the working directory by using a single function (batch export).

**Details**:

*My question is not about changing the content of the data frames, so you can just use any example data provided by R for reproduction*.

The function I use for exporting a single data frame is

```
csvExport <- function(data, enc = 'utf8'){
    name <- paste(deparse(substitute(data)), "csv", sep=".")
    con <- file(name, encoding = enc)
    write.csv(data, file = con, row.names=FALSE, quote = TRUE, sep = ";")
    text<-"exported!"
    print(paste(name, text, sep=" "))
}
```

Since I do not like to call the function for each data frame to export explicitly I am looking for a way to export the data frames by indicating which ones from the workspace I like to export with:

```
export <- ls()[1:20]
```

I then tried using this function (with some variation of the for loop) with the above list:

```
multipleCSVExport <- function(export){
  for (i in export){
    csvExport(i)
  }
}
```

However, I am not able to create the expected result.

Comment: You'll probably need to re-write your `csvExport` function so that the `data` argument is a character, which is really what you should have done in the first place, most likely. `get` will be useful.

Comment: The name will always be i.csv; change that line

Comment: @ joran: This solved my problem, thanks. Maybe you can turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `mget` to turn your data.frames in the workspace into a list of data.frame and then use `lapply` or a `for` loop.

```
list_df <- mget(ls()[1:20])

lapply(seq_along(list_df),
       function(i) write.table(list_df[[i]], 
                               paste0(names(list_df)[i], ".csv"),
                               row.names = FALSE, quote = TRUE, 
                               sep = ";", dec = "."))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `qdap` package has just such a function: `mscv_w`.  The dev version is what you're after and can be downloaded here (follow directions): https://github.com/trinker/qdap#installation

So something like this works:

```
mcsv_w(mtcars, CO2, dir="foo")
```

And if you're more interested in how the function works here is the source code: https://github.com/trinker/qdap/blob/master/R/mcsv_r.R